# Error: no name paramenter with name: 'trackCameraPosition: true' in flutter

Tags: android, firebase, google-maps, flutter, flutter-dependencies

When run `flutter` `run -v`, it works.
But on `flutter` run, it display this error,

```
The following _CompileTimeError was thrown building FireMap(dirty, state: FireMapState#0f0b0):
I/flutter (13678): 'package:google_tracker/main.dart': error: lib/main.dart:39:9: Error: No named parameter with the
I/flutter (13678): name 'trackCameraPosition'.
I/flutter (13678):         trackCameraPosition: true,
I/flutter (13678):         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Here is my main.dart:

````
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';


void main() => runApp(MyApp());
GoogleMapController mapController;

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: FireMap(),
      ), 
    );
  }     
}

class FireMap extends StatefulWidget {
  State createState() => FireMapState();
}

class FireMapState extends State<FireMap> {
GoogleMapController mapController;
  build(context) {
    return Stack(children: [
      GoogleMap(
          initialCameraPosition:  CameraPosition(
        target: LatLng(9.05785, 7.49508),
        zoom: 15,

      ),

       onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
        myLocationEnabled: true,
        mapType: MapType.hybrid,
        compassEnabled: true,
        trackCameraPosition: true, 

      ),

      Positioned(
        bottom: 50,
        right: 10,
        child:
        FlatButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.pin_drop, color: Colors.white),
        color: Colors.green,
        onPressed: () => _addMarker()  
        )
      )


    ]);
  }

  _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    setState(() {
      mapController = controller;
    });
  }
}

_addMarker() {
  var marker = MarkerOptions(
    position: mapController.cameraPosition.target,
    icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
    infoWindowText: InfoWindowText('Magic Marker', '')
  );

  mapController.addMarker(marker);
}```

How do i solve this, thanks
````

Answer (score 4):

For fellow user that use same tutorial fireship.io too. The trackCameraPosition has been remove, so now you can use onCameraMove. You can find the example at https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/google_maps_flutter/example/lib/map_ui.dart

for quick preview

```
class FireMapState extends State<FireMap> {

 static final CameraPosition _kInitialPosition = const CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(24.150, -110.32),
    zoom: 10,
  );

  CameraPosition _position = _kInitialPosition;

  build(context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        GoogleMap(
          initialCameraPosition: _kInitialPosition,
          onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
          myLocationEnabled: true,
          mapType: MapType.hybrid,
          onCameraMove: _updateCameraPosition,
        ),

  ...

  }

  ...

  void _updateCameraPosition(CameraPosition position) {
    setState(() {
      _position = position;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: #Santo, Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

`GoogleMap` widget does not have a `trackCameraPosition` property.

Comment: I was following a tutorial, the tutor trackCameraPosition for that, https://fireship.io/lessons/flutter-realtime-geolocation-firebase.

Comment: `trackCameraPosition` was removed since version 0.4.0. According to the [package's changelog](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter#-changelog-tab-): `trackCameraPosition is inferred from GoogleMap.onCameraMove being set.`

Comment: Thanks very much, your comment was helpful.  So, how do make use of the ```onCameraMove?  Do I just change it from ```trackCameraPosition to ```.onCameraMove like this                                                                                                                                                  onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
        myLocationEnabled: true,
        mapType: MapType.hybrid,
        compassEnabled: true,
       onCameraMove: true, 
Thanks